# Convert header (column names) to new dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with headers for example `outputDF`. I now want to take `outputDF.columns` and create a new dataframe with just one row which contains column names. 
I then want to union both these dataframes with `option("head=false")` which spark can then write to a HDFS.

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

below is an example

```
Val df = spark.read.csv("path")
val newDf = df.columns.toSeq.toDF
val unoindf= df.union(newDf);
```

Comment: this is using the first row of df to create newDf, not creating a row with the column names